# How to leave blank columns in a CSV file

Tags: php

I have a script that stores results of a form to a CSV file on the server.

I have to make another form doing the same thing but instead of filling all the columns in the CSV file, I only need to fill in few selected and leave the rest as blank.

Currently, this is what I am using to write to my CSV:

```
$data = "$Name" . ',' . "$Address" . ',' . "$Email" . ',' . "$Cell_Phone". ',' . "$selected". $cr;
```

How can I now leave the $cell_phone and `$selected` columns as blank?

Comment: Start by learning about PHP's fputcsv() function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and all of a sudden it will become really easy

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am reading that right now!

Comment: if you are looking for a way to return a csv to the browser and dont' want to create a temporary file you can just `$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");` then use the `$fp` handle for your fputcsv calls

Comment: @Orangepill: That is what I am using already in my code. I was just not sure of the best practice, should I leave the variable as null or how else can I leave a column blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying what I think you are... then the simple answer is to ensure that those variables are empty strings (or `null`).

The better answer has already been suggested: learn how to use [`fputcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be:

```
$data = "$Name" . ',' . "$Address" . ',' . "$Email" . ',,' . $cr;
```

However, as Mark Baker pointed out, this way of creating CSV files is not really recommended. You should use PHP's own CSV functions like [`fputcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).